# WP_Query returning no results

Tags: wp-query

I have the following code to merge 3 different queries:

```
<div class="features-list">
            <?php

                $args1 = array (
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post__not_in' => array(2, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 61, 116, 129, 58665, 58666, 58667, 58668, 57800, 62883, 74802, 75597, 75599, 75601, 75609),
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
                    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
                    'meta_value' => 'template-features.php'
                );
            $query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );

            // If there are results, then push the IDs into an array
            $query1_posts = array();
            if ( $query1->have_posts() ) { 
              while( $query1->have_posts() ) {
                $query1->the_post();
                array_push( $query1_posts, get_the_ID() );
              }
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();

                $args2 = array (
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'meta_key' => 'feature_type',
            'meta_value' => 'guide'
                );
            $query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

            // If there are results, then push the IDs into an array
            $query2_posts = array();
            if ( $query2->have_posts() ) { 
              while( $query2->have_posts() ) {
                $query2->the_post();
                array_push( $query2_posts, get_the_ID() );
              }
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();

                $args3 = array (
            'post_type' => 'new_features',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'meta_key' => 'feature_type',
            'meta_value' => 'guide'
                );
            $query3 = new WP_Query( $args3 );

            // If there are results, then push the IDs into an array
            $query3_posts = array();
            if ( $query3->have_posts() ) { 
              while( $query3->have_posts() ) {
                $query3->the_post();
                array_push( $query3_posts, get_the_ID() );
              }
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();

            $results = array_unique ( array_merge( $query1_posts, $query2_posts, $query3_posts ) );

            // WP_Query arguments
            $the_args = array (
              'post__in' => $results
            );

            // The Query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $the_args );
                $count = 1;

                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
                while ($the_query -> have_posts()) {
                    $the_query -> the_post();
            ?>
            <article class="<?php if ($count == 1) { ?>g1_2<? } else { ?>g1_4<?php } ?>">
                <div class="feature_image">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ($count == 1) { the_post_thumbnail('full'); } else { the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); } ?></a>
                    <div class="feature_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></div>
                </div>
                <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
            </article>
            <?php
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </div><!-- .features-list -->
```

I know that $results has all the post IDs I need, but still the $the_query returns no posts.

What am I missing. I rewrote this code at least 10 times by now.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump( $results )` ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The output contained the array of posts, that's why I was lost. The answer accepted below fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might also need to set the 'post_type' in `$the_args`, and possibly the 'posts_per_page';
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters

example:

```
    // WP_Query arguments
    $the_args = array (
      'post__in' => $results,
  'post_type' => array( 'any' ),
  'posts_per_page' => 10
    );
```

Comment: This seemed to work. At least the posts are showing.Thanks a lot for your help!